# Read Barcode [Live] On Desktop Browser and get the value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, barcode, barcode-scanner

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>

 #outer
 {
  height:100%;
  margin:0px auto;
  border: 1px solid;
     background: url("https://preview.ibb.co/gYykLn/images.jpg");
     height: auto;
      width:auto;
     background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 }
 #form
 {
  position: relative;
 height: auto;
 width: 250px;
 left: 70%;
 bottom: 10%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
 border-color: #ffa200;
 border-width: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;

 }


   .logo
   {

    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left: 10px; 
    
   }

    .lgo
    {

     position: absolute;
     right: 215px;
     top: 56px;

    }
 .first
 {
        height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-top:40px;
  
 }

 .a
 {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-top:20px;
 }

    .a:hover
    {
     border-color: #ffa200;
    }



     .first:hover
    {
     border-color: #ffa200;
    }

 .b
 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color: #ffa200;
  border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:30px;
 }

    .b:hover
    {
     background-color: #dd8c00;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="outer">
  <div id="form">
   <form>
      <img class="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/bAvSi7/download.png" >   
      <input class="a first" type="text" name="regno"  required/>
          <img class="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/jpgGRS/l1.png" >          
    <input class="a " type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
    <img class="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/cSWuD7/l3.png" >
    <input class="a" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required/>
    <img class="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/eeGSY7/l2.png" >
    <input class="a" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter your password" required/>
    <img class="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/eeGSY7/l2.png" >
    <input class="a" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm your password" required/>
    <img class="logo" src="https://image.ibb.co/bKqX0n/l4.jpg" >
    <input class="a" type="tel" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" required/>
    <input class="b" type="submit" value="Register"/>
     
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a registration page designed that looks like **ABOVE** html

I want a pop-up window to be displayed as soon as we land up on page and it request to 'scan the barcode to continue' and

**It will get the value from barcode using desktop/laptop webcam**  (*The bar code is actually on our college ID card, which has the value that is OUR registration Number*) **and put the value on the ID textfield** (*which is disabled i.e. user cannot edit that textbox*)

Comment: This is not a matter of a single stackoverflow answer. Research how javascript multimedia API works. You will also have to find yourself barcode scanning library.

If you can't do that, you'll have to hire someone to do it.

Comment: For getting the value from barcode using webcam, you can try [this demo](https://demo.dynamsoft.com/DBR_Webcam/WebcamBarcodeReader.html). It uses Dynamsoft Barcode Reader library.